# Showing that the functional $L[h(x)]=\int_{a}^{b}h(x)f(x)dx$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Suppose that we have the functional $L: L^2[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ , $L[h(x)]=\int_{a}^{b}h(x)f(x)dx$. $f(x)$ is a well behaving, integrable function in $L^2[a,b]$. I want to show that this is a linear functional. A linear functional is defined as: 
[image]

It is very easy to show that this is additive. But I am having difficulty to show that it is continuous. It must be $\lim_{||h_n(x) - h(x)||\to 0}L[h_n(x)] = L[h(x)]$.

Assuming that we use the $L^2$ norm, I tried to show the following:
For each $\epsilon > 0$ there must be a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $h_n(x)$:

$$ 0 <||h_n(x) - h(x)|| < \delta \implies \left| L[h_n(x)] - L[h(x)] \right| < \epsilon$$

$$ 0 < \left( \int_{a}^{b} \left| h_n(x)-h(x) \right| ^2dx \right) ^{1/2} < \delta \implies \left| \int_{a}^{b}(h_n(x) -h(x))f(x)dx \right| < \epsilon$$

What I have tried is the following: First, I defined $M=\max_{a \leq x \leq b}|f(x)|$. Then I fixed a $\epsilon > 0$ such that $M\int_{a}^{b}|h_n(x) -h(x)|dx < \epsilon$. It is: $$\left| \int_{a}^{b}(h_n(x) -h(x))f(x)dx \right| \leq M\int_{a}^{b}|h_n(x) -h(x)|dx < \epsilon$$. I intended to find all $h_n(x)$ which obeys the inequality above and relate them to $\epsilon$ in order to find a $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $\left( \int_{a}^{b} \left| h_n(x)-h(x) \right| ^2dx \right) ^{1/2} < \delta(\epsilon)$ but I failed to find a way to do it; the square on $|h_n(x)-h(x)|$ blocks me. How should I proceed here? I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if you are considering $L:C[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, then $L$ is clearly a linear functional. Now note that for any $h \in C[0,1]$
\begin{equation}
|L(h)| =\biggl{|}\int_\limits{a}^{b}h(x)f(x)dx\biggr{|}\leq (b-a)\sup_{a\leq x\leq b}|h(x)f(x)| \leq (b-a)\sup_{a\leq x\leq b}|h(x)|\sup_{a\leq x\leq b}|f(x)|,
\end{equation}
i.e.,
\begin{equation}
|L(h)| \leq (b-a)\|f\|\|h\|.
\end{equation}
Hence $L$ is a bounded linear functional and in particular, it follows that $L$ is continuous.

Now if you want this for $L:L^2[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, then what you can do is the following
\begin{align}
|L(h)| &=\biggl{|}\int_\limits{a}^{b}h(x)f(x)dx\biggr{|}\\
&\leq \int_\limits{a}^{b}|h(x)||f(x)|dx\\
&\leq \left(\int_\limits{a}^{b}|h(x)|^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_\limits{a}^{b}|h(x)|^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}&& (\text{Holder's Inequality})\\
&= \|h\|_2\|f\|_2.
\end{align}
So, $L$ is bounded and hence continuous.

Comment: Actually I intend to show this by using the $L^2$ norm, such that $L$ is defined $L:L^2[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! It is hard to get a proper answer like this in this board nowadays...

Comment: your welcome!!!